# Carry Data Table value one place to another place, in windows Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows

I have text box control & a button, After putting value in text box & Click on button data should be added in data table.

The problem which i face is, when i added new record, previous record are gone,& new record are come in place of old record.

I come to know, what i use in Windows Application to carry data to one place to another. [viewstate] which we use in WebApplication, But what to do for window application

In this code, it add only one record in the table, when i try to add 2nd record it make replace the old one.

My code are:

```
public void Getdatatable(int srno, string Name, string address, int contactno,double amount,string Emailid)
{

    try 
    {
         dt = new DataTable();
        DataRow dr;

            dt.Columns.Add(new System.Data.DataColumn("SrNo", typeof(int)));
            dt.Columns.Add(new System.Data.DataColumn("Name", typeof(string)));
            dt.Columns.Add(new System.Data.DataColumn("address", typeof(string)));
            dt.Columns.Add(new System.Data.DataColumn("ContactNo", typeof(int)));
            dt.Columns.Add(new System.Data.DataColumn("amount", typeof(double)));
            dt.Columns.Add(new System.Data.DataColumn("Emailid", typeof(string)));
            dr = dt.NewRow();


            dr[0] = srno;
            dr[1] = Name;
            dr[2] = address;
            dr[3] = contactno;
            dr[4] = amount;
            dr[5] = Emailid;

            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {}    
}

private void btnadd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    srno =Convert.ToInt32(txtsrno.Text);
    Name = txtname.Text;
    address = txtaddress.Text;
    contactno =Convert.ToInt32(txtcontact.Text);
    amount =Convert.ToDouble(txtamount.Text);
    Emailid = txtemail.Text;

    Getdatatable(srno, Name, address, contactno, amount, Emailid);
    //dt = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][0];
    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
    {

                dr[0] = txtsrno.Text;
                dr[1] = txtname.Text;
                dr[2] = txtaddress.Text;
                dr[3] = txtcontact.Text;
                dr[4] = txtamount.Text;
                dr[5] = txtemail.Text;

    }
    dt.AcceptChanges();
    grd.DataSource = dt;

    txtsrno.Text = "";
    txtname.Text = "";
    txtaddress.Text = "";
    txtcontact.Text = "";
    txtamount.Text = "";
    txtemail.Text = "";            
}
```

Comment: Why is this tagged both `asp.net` and `win apps` ?

Comment: Where you want to carry to the next form or you want to use the same object in the same form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well... Your Getdatatable method is creating a new table.
Since you are calling this method in your Click callback, the table is created anew each time. Therefore you only get the last element added.

You should create your table once and remove the Getdatatable(srno, Name, address, contactno, amount, Emailid); call from your button callback.

Answer (score 0):

You could declare `DataTable dt` as global variable and add columns to it once when form is loaded.

```
private DataTable dt = null;

private void CreateTable() 
{
    dt = new DataTable();

    dt.Columns.Add(new System.Data.DataColumn("SrNo", typeof(int)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new System.Data.DataColumn("Name", typeof(string)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new System.Data.DataColumn("address", typeof(string)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new System.Data.DataColumn("ContactNo", typeof(int)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new System.Data.DataColumn("amount", typeof(double)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new System.Data.DataColumn("Emailid", typeof(string)));
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CreateTable();
}
```

After the `CreateTable` method was called, you will have data table with columns you want and you don't need to call this method again when you try to add data row to the data table.

Here is the button click event handler

```
private void ClearTextBox() 
{
    txtsrno.Text = "";
    txtname.Text = "";
    txtaddress.Text = "";
    txtcontact.Text = "";
    txtamount.Text = "";
    txtemail.Text = "";      
}

private void btnadd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        srno = Convert.ToInt32(txtsrno.Text);
        Name = txtname.Text;
        address = txtaddress.Text;
        contactno = Convert.ToInt32(txtcontact.Text);
        amount = Convert.ToDouble(txtamount.Text);
        Emailid = txtemail.Text;

        DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr[0] = srno;
        dr[1] = Name;
        dr[2] = address;
        dr[3] = contactno;
        dr[4] = amount;
        dr[5] = Emailid;

        dt.Rows.Add(dr);

        dt.AcceptChanges();
        grd.DataSource = dt;

        ClearTextBox();
    }
    catch (Exception ex) { /*Handle Exception*/ } 
}
```

Otherwise, you don't need to have those TextBoxes and button for add data to data table. You just code like this, and enter data in DataGridView cell directly (like when you edit excel file).

```
private DataTable dt = null;

private void CreateTable() 
{
    dt = new DataTable();

    dt.Columns.Add(new System.Data.DataColumn("SrNo", typeof(int)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new System.Data.DataColumn("Name", typeof(string)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new System.Data.DataColumn("address", typeof(string)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new System.Data.DataColumn("ContactNo", typeof(int)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new System.Data.DataColumn("amount", typeof(double)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new System.Data.DataColumn("Emailid", typeof(string)));

    grd.DataSource = dt;
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CreateTable();
}
```